# delete particular tableview item in SWRevealViewController in objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

Hi how to remove particular table view cells in SWRevealViewController .my table View cells are hard coded in story board.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.row==2)
   {
      return 0.0;
   }
   if(indexPath.row==3)
   {
      return 0.0;
   } 
     return 75;
}
```

While running first time its messed up.once click that particular cell its working properly.

Here the Screen Shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUNoi.jpg

Answer (score 1):

**Do as follows**

1.Create Number of dynamic cells as per your needs(how much items you want to show).

2.Give different identifier to all of your cells.

3.Make a array of identifiers of all of yours cell in the sequence in which you want to show the cells. identifierArray[] in my case.

4.Then in numberOfItems inSection, return identifierArry.count.

5.Simply in cellForRow atIndexpath, dequeue your cell with identifier: identifierArray[indexpat.row].

6.if You want to delete any row then simply remove the identifier from IdentifierArray like so identifierArray.removeObject[position]. where position is the position of your item in array.

7.And after removing the identifier from array call tableView.reloadData method.

Hope it will help you.
Note: If it will solve your problem then not forget to mark this as accepted by checking the tick mark.

Comment: In my case i hard coded all my cells in story board